# latex is not being recognized in RStudio

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, quarto

I am trying to setup my system to render PDFs with rmarkdown and quarto, so I installed **tinytex** by running **tinytex::install_tinytex()**. when i run the render/knit i am getting the following error

```
running xelatex - 1
command xelatex not found, attempting install
finding package for xelatex
> 1 package to install
> installing xelatex (1 of 1)
ERROR: Error executing 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\xelatex': This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator. (os error 1260)
```

i don't have administrative powers since the laptop belongs to the company. so i told the IT guy to run the **xelatex.exe** file and also to add that path to environment variables. but i am still getting the same error.

what could be the issue and how to solve it? thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This might be related to a bug where quarto was not able to find the new version of texlive (2023)

Its worth trying to update texlive AND update to the new RC of quarto.

https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/4908

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34177581)